# What value could the user input to make the loop continue? (Python Menu Of Choices)

Tags: python, loops

This is a practise question from our computer sciences textbook which I don't get at all and my professor hasnt briefed us on this topic.
Basically, a **menu interface** is made which was inside a **while loop**. The first line of the while loop is:

```
while more == "Y":
```

> 1- what is the name of the variable used in this command?
>
> 2- What value could the user input to make the loop continue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please give more information about the question? You can share more of your code. You can also check here to how to ask a clear question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.